# jquery Load data from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to read a html file using jQuery.get() without success.
I've put a breakpoint on 'var x = 1' but the execution does not reach that point.
The javascript function is:

```
function do_about()
{        
    $.get('mytest/index.html', function(data) {
        var x = 1;        
    }).error(function() { alert("error"); });   
};
```

The alert("error") is raised, however (as I am "dummy" in javascript) I don't know how to catch the error message correctly. The jQuery.get() documentation says:

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method or. As of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.get() is also available for error handling.

There is no remote web server, it is local.My Apache (on Ubuntu 11.04) is running and the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default there is the following entry for the desired file:

```
Alias /mytest /home/miro/mytest
<Directory "/home/miro/mytest">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In Firefox if I call the url **http://localhost/mytest/index.html** the page will be displayed without problem.

The mytest/index.html is:

```
<html><body><h1>Test page</h1></body></html>
```

I tried `$.get('http://localhost/mytest/index.html', function(data) {....`
and it did not work.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Is there any other way to read a html using just javascript (no jQuery)? I just want to get some tag values from that html ?

Comment: Does Firebug Console / Webkit Console report any error?

Comment: So can you access the file by putting the address in your browser? Are you currently on a `http://localhost` page?

Comment: Is your do_about() function getting called? Normally the ready function is not used within a method, rather it is in just a <script> block.

Comment: what happens if you alert(data) in your callback? anything? and your calling do_about, right?

Comment: why would you put $(document).ready() inside function, this event would never be triggered, as your function is called after such event.

Comment: Yes, do_about() is called. I'm doing my tests locally, so it is possible to access the file via http://localhost/mytest/index.html.

Comment: Don't give up on jQuery just yet :) jQuery can still help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be a path issue try setting your path relative to the domain root like so:

```
$.get('/mytest/index.html', function(data) {
    var x = 1;
});
```

Comment: "Hi doctor. I'm sick. Heal me"

Answer (score 0):

Can you console log the errors you receive? so we know if its a server issue or some redirects.

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/